# The Weyl tensor and gravitational waves

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, gravitational-waves

How exactly is the [Weyl tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) is connected with information about [gravitational waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave)? And what are physical reasons for that?

Comment: See this article on Weyl tensor and gravitational waves http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2768

Comment: or http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/ricci.weyl.html for some more approachable background information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Weyl tensor is the trace-free part of the Riemann tensor. The latter describes the curvature of spacetime. In the absence of sources, the trace part of the Riemann tensor will vanish due to the Einstein equations, but the Weyl tensor can still be non-zero. This is the case for gravitational waves propagating in vacuum.

The physical reason is that even in the absence of sources, there can be curvature of space time. Gravitational waves represent small variations of curvature, i.e. non-zero curvature. An analogous situation would be electromagnetic waves propagating in vacuum. One can describe them by the source-free Maxwell equations without specifying anything about charges or currents that might have produced them.

Comment: Thanks. Is it's connection with gravitational waves somehow connected with conformal invariance of the Weyl tensor?

Comment: I do not think that it is related to gravitational waves as such, but rather to the fact that it describes vacuum: one could argue that in the absence of matter, there is no mass scale and hence the theory is conformally invariant. The conformal invariance of the Weyl tensor then reflects this property.